# Conditionally add attribute to component

Tags: angularjs

I have a `register-task-popup` component which can use the `personId` data:

```
<register-task-popup
    person-id="${personId}"
    chat-customer-information='${JSON.stringify(chatCustomerInformation)}'
</register-task-popup>`;
```

The `personId` data is optional, sometimes it's available, sometimes it's not. Is it possible to only add the `person-id` attribute when `personId` is not undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below is working for me -

```
<register-task-popup 
 {{( personId == '') ? "" : "person-id=''"+ personId+"''" }} chat-customer- 
 information='${JSON.stringify(chatCustomerInformation)}'>
 </register-task-popup>`;
```

Comment: Yup, `${personId ? `person-id="${personId}"` : ``}` worked great :)

Comment: @PeterBoomsma, great to know.